# Reputation Change without Notification

Tags: support, reputation

I'm pretty sure that yesterday my rep was 9489. It then changed to 9499 and later to 9497. I didn't get any notification. Are there recalculations running?

Comment: I can confirm that the 9499 to 9497 is from a recalc. I can only assume that one of your upvotes yesterday raised you from 9489 to 9499 - it doesn't look like a recalc to me.

Comment: I also had that, but only +2. My experience told me that often it meant that some posts you may have downvoted were deleted by their owners; but it makes more sense that this is a recalc.

Comment: @mixedmath I checked my recent upvotes and there was none. But maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. These recalculations have to do with the recent deletion of an account with a very large number of votes. Initially the  user's votes were deleted  (as usually  happens), but they were restored several hours ago. The reputation  timelines of the affected users were amended retroactively.

Comment: Define "large number of votes".

Comment: @Asaf: The deleted user was in the first page of all time voters. I think that would qualify for "large number of votes". See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13869/11619). IIRC you also got a bump, but some other users may have only received downvotes from the said user. May be now those downvotes were also restored? If your change was only 2 rep points, then this is probably something else.

Comment: @Jyrki: I also had some points deducted last week, presumably from the same user. But that was indicated as a user removal. Are you suggesting that these votes were reinstated?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, if we are talking about the same user (May 30 deletion). Your reputation timeline no longer shows that particular "user removed" (if it ever did; I did not check it before)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. Olivier Begassat, who opened the meta thread linked by Jyrki, has no records of a user removal in the reputation timeline either.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So, SE cleaned up pretty thoroughly. The only place where the reputation hasn't been fixed (yet) is the [Network reputation page](http://stackexchange.com/users/510581/georges-elencwajg?tab=reputation) of Georges Elencwajg. The graph still has a drop, and looking at the page source (which has all day-by-day reputation values) one can still see `63865, 62730` on consecutive days. But this is only on the network profile, not on the site profile. Perhaps the network page will catch up later.

Comment: Perhaps in the future a whistleblower a-la Snowden will escape from SE Inc. and will reveal the truth about this operation. The entire site is a bitcoin mine to fund the alien government which rules the Western world from the center of the Sun!